# Rails 3: Why `errors` Hash is empty for nested model (all errors are in the parent model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Devise and have models set up like this:

```
User
    has_one :profile
Profile
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :address
Address 
    belongs_to :profile
```

For testing, I caused errors on the form (it's a nested form, using all 3 models). This is the resulting errors hash (`@user.errors hash`):

```
{
:email=>["can't be blank"], 
:password_confirmation=>[], 
:password=>["can't be blank"],
:"profile.first_name"=>["can't be blank","is too short (minimum is 1 characters)"]
:"profile.address.street"=>["can't be blank"], 
}
```

All the errors are expected, but the hash's key format is unexpected (`:"profile.address.street"`) - I would have thought each nested model's `errors` hash would contain the errors for that model ?

I checked inside the `@user.profile.errors` hash, and that is empty!

How do I get the nested-model specific errors into the relevant `errors` hash in the nested model?

**UPDATE**

I hacked out a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4371184/382818). Had a question on that too, so the solution isn't posted as an answer to this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this not too long ago and had to cook up some code to pluck these out myself. It isn't supported by default in Rails - Ryan Daigle touches on it [here a bit](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@user.profile.valid?
@user.profile.errors
```

Comment: Great! Called `valid?` in the view and it's working. BTW, is there some way to patch some class so this will happen automatically instead of having to call it in every view?

Comment: Glad that worked for you. You could override `valid?` or `errors` in your `User` model, but I don't recommend it if the simple method above works.

Comment: Actually, this did not help much since calling `valid?` shows up the error messages even when the submit button is not pressed (i.e. GETting the page displays the errors!). Please look at my solution in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4371184/382818 ?